# How efficient is PHP's substr?

Tags: php, optimization, memory-management, substr

I'm writing a parser in PHP which must be able to handle large in-memory strings, so this is a somewhat important issue. (ie, please don't "premature optimize" flame me, please)

How does the `substr` function work? Does it make a second copy of the string data in memory, or does it reference the original? Should I worry about calling, for example, `$str = substr($str, 1);` in a loop?

Comment: I would think that the assignment would be the killer, not the substr.

Comment: [FFI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ffi.php) extension may help, but it needs to be enabled in php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further Chad's comment, your code would require both strings (the full one, and the full-one-minus-first-character) to be in memory at the same time (though not due to the assignment as Chad stated). See:

```
$string = str_repeat('x', 1048576);
printf("MEM:  %d\nPEAK: %d\n", memory_get_usage(), memory_get_peak_usage());

substr($string, 1);
printf("MEM:  %d\nPEAK: %d  :-(\n", memory_get_usage(), memory_get_peak_usage());

$string = substr($string, 1);
printf("MEM:  %d\nPEAK: %d  :-(\n", memory_get_usage(), memory_get_peak_usage());
```

Outputs something like (memory values are in bytes):

```
MEM:  1093256
PEAK: 1093488
MEM:  1093280
PEAK: 2142116  :-(
MEM:  1093276
PEAK: 2142116  :-(
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're really looking into efficiency, you will need to keep a pointer - I mean *index* - with your string. Many string functions accept an offset to start operating from (like [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)'s third parameter). Normally I would recommend writing an object to wrap this functionality, but if you're expecting to use that a lot, that might cause a performance bottleneck. Here is an example of what I mean (without OO):

```
while ($whatever) {
    $pos = strpos($string, $myToken, $startIndex);
    # do something using $pos
    $startIndex = $pos;
}
```

If you want, you can write your own wrapper class that does these string operations and see if it has a speed impact:

```
class _String {
    private $string;
    private $startIndex;
    private $length;
    public function __construct($string) {
        $this->string = $string;
        $this->startIndex = 0;
        $this->length = strlen($string);
    }
    public function substr($from, $length = NULL) {
        $this->startIndex = $from;
        if ($length !== NULL) {
            $this->endIndex = $from + $length;
        }
    }
    # other functions you might use
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Normal Java strings do these things automatically. Why doesn't PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be careful doing any string manipulation inside a loop as new copies of the string will be generated on each iteration.

Comment: I'm not a php guy, so you might simply say nope. In Java, it only creates a new reference to the same immutable char array. So while it creates a new String object, it doesn't take store more copies of the underlying char array. It merely declares the offsets to be different. Does php actually create a new copy of the char array? Or only reference the same char array.